# Гиперссылка Python pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qlabel

У меня есть приложение, в котором я хочу сделать гиперссылку, чтобы ссылка была кликабельной и называлась не "https://ru.stackoverflow.com/", а "Перейти по ссылке".

Переход должен осуществляться на сайт "https://ru.stackoverflow.com/".

[image: Пример]

**test.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(652, 273)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 0, 101, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(22)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 120, 321, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ссылка"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "https://ru.stackoverflow.com/"))
```

**untitled.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from test import Ui_MainWindow


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

#from test import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(652, 273)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 0, 101, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(22)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 120, 321, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ссылка"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "https://ru.stackoverflow.com/"))


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.label.setText('<a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/"> Ссылка </a>')

        # Указывает, должен ли QLabel автоматически открывать ссылки с помощью QDesktopServices.openUrl() 
        # вместо того, чтобы излучать сигнал QLabel.linkActivated().
        self.label.setOpenExternalLinks(True)

        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget) 
        vbox.addWidget(self.label)


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно ли изменить цвет текста "Ссылка"?

Comment: @imapw_ можно   `self.label.setText('<a style="color:red;" href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/"> Ссылка </a>')`, но это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: спасибо, вы мне очень помогли